# Python Tkinter adding icons to notebook tabs using a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this piece of code which is supposed to add tabs with icons to the tabs from the mainAppTabs list:

`[["home", getcwd()+"/icons/homeIcon.png"],["log", getcwd()+"/icons/homeIcon.png"],["data", getcwd()+"/icons/homeIcon.png"],["options", getcwd()+"/icons/homeIcon.png"]]`

```
for i,v in enumerate(mainAppTabs):
   v.insert(1, Frame(mainAppNotebook, width=850, height=300))
   v[1].grid_propagate(False)
   icon = PhotoImage(file=v[2])
   mainAppNotebook.add(v[1], text = v[0].title(), image = icon, compound = "left")
```

However, it only adds an icon to the final tab, and the icon it adds is the icon that is meant for the first tab.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Try saving each instance of `PhotoImage` in a list or dictionary.

Comment: @BryanOakley I thought I had tried this already, but obviously not. Nevertheless, this worked, so thank you!